# The set of ground model reals arbitrarily close to a new real in the forcing extension

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Consider a forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$, a condition $p\in\mathbb{P}$, a $\mathbb{P}$-name $\dot{r}$ and a formula (with ground model parameters) $\varphi(x)$ such that $$p \Vdash \dot{r} \in \omega^\omega \text{ and } \dot{r}\not\in \dot{V} \text{ and } \varphi(\dot{r})$$
where $\dot{V}$ is the definition of the ground model in the forcing extension. Now, every condition $q$ extending $p$ will still force the above formula (hence it won't decide the value of $\dot{r}$), and there will be a maximal finite sequence $s_q \in \omega^{<\omega}$ such that $q\Vdash \check{s_q}\sqsubset \dot{r}$, where $\sqsubset$ means "it is properly extended", so in this case $s_q$ is the best $q$ can decide about the initial segment of $\dot{r}$.

Consider now the following set (where $p$ and $\dot{r}$ are as above): $$A(p, \dot{r}) = \{x \in \omega^\omega \mid \forall q \le p \ (s_q \sqsubset x \rightarrow \exists r\le q \ \ s_q\sqsubset s_r\sqsubset x)\}$$ so this set (defined in the ground model) is the one, in a certain strong sense, of all those reals that can be forced to be arbitrarly close to $\dot{r}$.
For example, if $\mathbb{P}$ is the Cohen forcing adding one Cohen real and $\varphi(x): x=x$ (the trivial formula) then $A(1_{\mathbb{P}}, \dot{G}) = \omega^\omega$, where $\dot{G}$ is the canonical name of the generic object.

My questions are:

- Does this set remind you of anything known and studied?
- Suppose that $p\Vdash \exists x(x \in \omega^\omega \text{ and } x\not\in \dot{V} \text{ and } \varphi(x))$, is there a name $\dot{r}$ and a condition $q\le p$ such that $A(q,\dot{r})$ is big, or, to be more precise, such that $A(q,\dot{r})\cap \{x\in\omega^\omega \mid \varphi(x)\}$ has non-empty interior in $\{x\in\omega^\omega \mid \varphi(x)\}$?

Ideas? Suggestions?
Thanks!